# mysql insert many unique rows from table to table based on column value

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to insert multiple rows of data from one table into another table that if there exist a row with with duplicate value in column liquorcode then just don't insert it. I found the following solution on here, however its for sql server, not mysql, it might also be better to have a solution using join.

```
insert into tblBusinessName(BusinessFilterPhrase, BusinessCategoryID)
select @BusinessFilterPhrase, @BusinessCategoryID
from tblBusinessName t1
where NOT EXISTS (select 1
                  from tblBusinessName d1
                  where d1.BusinessFilterPhrase = @BusinessFilterPhrase
                 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is basically fine for MySQL . . . as far as it goes.

If you want to ensure that `liquorcode` is unique, then you should have the database enforce this constraint, using a unique constraint or index:

```
 create unique index idx_tblBusinessName(liqurocode);
```

Then, when you do the insert, just ignore the error.  I prefer to do this using `on duplicate key update`.  Here is a version of such as query (of course, your example code doesn't use `liquorcode`, so I have to guess what you really mean):

```
insert into tblBusinessName(BusinessFilterPhrase, BusinessCategoryID)
    values (@BusinessFilterPhrase, @BusinessCategoryID)
    on duplicate key update BusinessCategoryId = values(BusinessCategoryId);
```

The `on duplicate key update` part basically does nothing (setting a column to itself).  Its purpose is to prevent an error on duplicates.